# Alert срабатывает столько раз, сколько закрыл popup. Почему?

Tags: javascript

Сколько раз закрыл попап, столько +1 и сработает alert. Почему?

```
"use strict";
(function($){
$(function(){
// Сам Popup
var popup =     '<div class="pmc">'+
'<div class="pmc_close"></div>'+
'<div class="popup_container">'+
'<div class="popup">'+
'<div class="popup__navigation">'+
'<div class="popup__navigation__search">'+
'<input class="search_input" type="text" name="search_input" value="" placeholder="Ваш поисковый запрос" autofocus="autofocus">'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="popup_close" title="Закрыть">X</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="popup__search">'+
'<div class="popup__search__block">'+
'<div class="popup__search_text">'+
'<h2>Где искать?</h2>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="popup__search__block">'+
'<div class="popup__search_select">'+
'<div class="block_label">'+
'<div id="bli_1" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">№ Брони</span>'+
'<input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="id">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'<div id="bli_2" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Дата</span>'+
'<input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="date">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'<div id="bli_3" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Дилер</span>'+
'<input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="dealer">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="block_label">'+
'<div id="bli_4" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Менеджер</span>'+
'<input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value=manager>'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'<div id="bli_5" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Бренд</span>'+
'<input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="brend">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="popup__search_select">'+
'<div class="block_label">'+
'<div id="bli_7" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">ИНН ЮЛ</span>'+
'<input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="ur_inn">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'<div id="bli_8" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Адрес</span>'+
'<input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="address" checked="checked">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'<div id="bli_9" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Оборудование</span>'+
'<input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="tool">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="block_label">'+
'<div id="bli_10" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Комментарий к проекту</span>'+
'<input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="comment_by_project">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'<div id="bli_11" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Не учитывать</span>'+
'<input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="none">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="popup__search__block">'+
'<div class="popup__search_text">'+
'<h2>Учитавать статус?</h2>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="popup__search__block">'+
'<div class="popup__search_select">'+
'<div class="block_label">'+
'<div id="bli_12" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Не учитывать</span>'+
'<input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="0" checked="checked">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'<div id="bli_13" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Не обработано</span>'+
'<input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="1">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="block_label">'+
'<div id="bli_14" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Авторизовано</span>'+
'<input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="2">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'<div id="bli_15" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Не авторизовано</span>'+
'<input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="3">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="block_label">'+
'<div id="bli_16" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Реализовано</span>'+
'<input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="4">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'<div id="bli_17" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Не реализовано</span>'+
'<input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="5">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="popup__search_select">'+
'<div class="block_label">'+
'<div id="bli_18" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Авторизация прекращена</span>'+
'<input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="6">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'<div id="bli_19" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Авторизация продлена</span>'+
'<input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="7">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="block_label">'+
'<div id="bli_20" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Авторизация просрочена</span>'+
'<input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="8">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'<div id="bli_21" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Запрос актуальности</span>'+
'<input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="9">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="popup__search__block">'+
'<div class="popup__search_text">'+
'<h2>Порядок вывода?</h2>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="popup__search__block">'+
'<div class="popup__search_select">'+
'<div class="block_label">'+
'<div id="bli_22" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Возрастание</span>'+
'<input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="sort" value="asc">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'<div id="bli_23" class="block_label__item">'+
'<label class="label_select_fild">'+
'<span class="label_select_fild__text">Убывание</span>'+
'<input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="sort" value="desc" checked="checked">'+
'</label>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="popup__footer">'+
'<div class="popup__footer__item">'+
'<input class="popup__footer__submit" type="button" name="popup__footer__submit" value="Найти">'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>';
var elem;
$('body').on('mouseover', '.search_btn', function (event) {
// Добавляем блюр
$('main').removeClass('custom_no_blur').addClass('custom_blur');
// Если не создан елемент с классом .pmc - создать, иначе показать
if ($('.pmc').length<1){$('footer').after(popup);$('.pmc').css({'display':'block'});}
else{$('.pmc').css({'display':'block'});}
$('.popup').fadeIn(800);
// Подсветим checked
$('.block_label__item input[checked="checked"]:radio').parent().parent().css({'background-color':'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3)', 'border-radius':'5px', 'color':'darkgreen'});
// выделяем при наведении
$('.block_label__item').on('mouseover', function() {
$(this).css({'background-color':'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3)', 'border-radius':'5px', 'color':'darkgreen'});
});
//снимаем выделение только у не выбранных
$('.block_label__item').on('mouseout', function() {
elem = $(this).children().children();
if ($(elem[1]).attr('checked') != 'checked'){
$(this).css({'background-color':'white', 'color':'#ccc'});
}
});
$('.block_label__item').on('click', function(event) {
elem = $(this).children().children();
var name = $(elem[1]).attr('name');
var mas_input = $('.block_label__item input[name="'+name+'"]');
for(let i=0; i<mas_input.length;i++){
$(mas_input[i]).attr('checked', false);
}
$('.block_label__item input[name="'+name+'"]').parent().parent().css({'background-color':'white', 'color':'#ccc'});
$(elem[1]).attr('checked', true);
$('.block_label__item input[checked="checked"]:radio').parent().parent().css({'background-color':'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3)', 'border-radius':'5px', 'color':'darkgreen'});
});
// Если нажата клавиша Enter начать поиск
$('.search_input').keydown(function(event){
if(event.keyCode===13){
var input=$('.block_label__item input[checked="checked"]:radio');
var searchStr=$('.search_input').val();
var searchField=$(input[0]).val();
var searchStatusId=$(input[1]).val();
var searchSort=$(input[2]).val();
if (searchField=='none'&searchStatusId=='0'){
$('main').removeClass('custom_blur').addClass('custom_no_blur');
$('.popup').fadeOut(800,function(){$('.pmc').css({'display':'none'});});
$('.loader-container').fadeIn(300);
let url = '/project/searchAjax/';
$.post(url,{searchStr:searchStr,searchField:searchField,searchStatusId:searchStatusId,searchSort:searchSort},function(data){
$('.blocks .table tbody').html(data);
$('.pagination').hide();
$('.loader-container').fadeOut(300,function(){$('.blocks .table tbody').ready().ajaxComplete();});
});
}else{
if(searchStr.length>2){
$('main').removeClass('custom_blur').addClass('custom_no_blur');
$('.popup').fadeOut(800,function(){$('.pmc').css({'display':'none'});});
$('.loader-container').fadeIn(300);
let url = '/project/searchAjax/';
$.post(url,{searchStr:searchStr,searchField:searchField,searchStatusId:searchStatusId,searchSort:searchSort},function(data){
$('.blocks .table tbody').html(data);
$('.pagination').hide();
$('.loader-container').fadeOut(300,function(){$('.blocks .table tbody').ready().ajaxComplete();});
});
}else{alert('Запрос должен быть не менее 3-х символов!');}
}
}
});
// Если нажата кнопка поиска - начать поиск
$('.popup__footer__submit').on('click',function(){
$('main').removeClass('custom_blur').addClass('custom_no_blur');
$('.popup').fadeOut(800,function(){$('.pmc').css({'display':'none'});});
$('.loader-container').fadeIn(300);
let input=$('.block_label__item input[checked="checked"]:radio');
let searchStr=$('.search_input').val();
let searchField=$(input[0]).val();
let searchStatusId=$(input[1]).val();
let searchSort=$(input[2]).val();
let url = '/project/searchAjax/';
$.post(url,{searchStr:searchStr,searchField:searchField,searchStatusId:searchStatusId,searchSort:searchSort},function(data){
$('.blocks .table tbody').html(data);
$('.pagination').hide();
$('.loader-container').fadeOut(300,function(){$('.blocks .table tbody').ready().ajaxComplete();});
});
});
$('.pmc_close').on('click', function (){
$('main').removeClass('custom_blur').addClass('custom_no_blur');
$('.popup').fadeOut(800, function () {
$('.pmc').css({'display':'none'});
});
});
$('.popup_close').on('click', function (){
$('main').removeClass('custom_blur').addClass('custom_no_blur');
$('.popup').fadeOut(800, function () {
$('.pmc').css({'display':'none'});
});
});
});
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: А как вы предлагаете читать вагон неотформатированного кода? В вопросе должен быть [минимальный и воспроизводимый](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) пример кода. Ни того, ни другого сейчас нет, равно как и нормального форматирования. Ну и держать огромный кусок HTML в JS коде - это, на мой взгляд, категорически неправильно

Comment: Как тогда вставить отформатированный? Я понял. Сейчас подправим.

Comment: @doox911 автоматическое форматирование есть, например, в [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net). Можно туда вставить код, нажать кнопку "Tidy", потом вставить сюда. Однако сделать пример минимальным и воспроизводимым сайт не сможет

Comment: @doox911 Что в вашем примере является $('main') ?

Comment: html тег. Использую для эффекта блюр.

Comment: @doox911 где ваш CSS

Comment: Весь не даёт скинуть, какой класс вывести?

Comment: @тут нет элемента main, нет вашего эффекта "блюр", нет стилей формы popUp, добавьте все это, а так же посмотрите ответ снизу, Alert вызывается один раз по нажатию enter если оставить поле пустым. PopUp форма закрывается и открывается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что событие срабатывает множество раз.

Попробуйте отвязать событие от элемента в начале выполнения и привязать в конце.

Comment: Решение:
$('.search_input').off();
Отвязал все события.